# Is System.Guid.NewGuid() always implemented through UuidCreate() on Windows?

Tags: .net, windows, guid

When my program written in C# or VB.NET or other .NET family language runs on Windows and calls `System.Guid.NewGuid()` is generation always performed by forwarding the call to `UuidCreate()` provided by Windows or are there other ways of generating?

Comment: The algorithm used to create Guid may matter if your code rely on its randomness.

Comment: As long as the function that generates the GUID follows the standard for UUID creation the chances of a collision are minimal.  See http://www.opengroup.org/dce/info/draft-leach-uuids-guids-01.txt for details on the algorithm

Answer (score 3):

No not always.  According to it's documentation, the [UuidCreate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379205(VS.85).aspx) function is only available on Windows Server 2000 and up.  At least one version of the .Net framework ran on Windows 98 and contained the `Guid` class.  Hence it could not have used UuidCreate. The 1.X for sure ran on Windows 98 and I can't remember about 2.0.

Hmmm, I'm beginning to suspect this is a documentation issue.  The [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(VS.85).aspx) function also says it's only available on 2000 and up.  Perhaps this documentation is a reflection of 98 not being a supported OS.